# Track visits/origin asp.net mvc website

Tags: web-analytics

I am not sure this is possible, I've certainly never tried doing this before but I have a customer who wants to be able to know where someone came from when they visited the site.  Was it from google, bing, a link from another website, etc.  More importantly as well they want to know if the visit is a product of normal SSO or if it was a paid add like adwords?

I would appreciate anyone's thoughts on this and if it's possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like google analytics. It should tell you pretty much all that information.